# Using struct Initializer to assign values to public member variables doesn't generate compiler error?

Tags: c++, variable-assignment, list-initialization

In the following C++ code, why does the struct initializer used with an assignment operator not generate a compiler error?

Is it a compiler bug?

Will it work on every compiler?

Which kind of assignment is it actually?

```
class vector2D
{
    public :
        double x,y;
};

int main()
{
    vector2D v1;
    v1 = {1,2} ; // why does this compile and work?
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it a compiler bug ?

No.

> Will it work on every compiler ?

It will compile on all C++11 (or later) compliant compilers.

> Which kind of assignment is it actually ?

It is assignment from a temporary object created with list initialisation.

Answer (score 1):

The right-hand side of an assignment can be a *braced-init-list*: it is converted to a value of some appropriate type (typically the left-hand-side type) to be assigned.  That it can be so converted is just **aggregate** initialization, as even C has had in some form forever (and as *compound literals* more recently).

Answer (score 1):

When a class does not have an explicitly defined assignment operator, an implicitly defined one exists.

In your case, there is an implicitly defined copy assignment operator of the form

```
vector2D& operator=(vector2D const& rhs);
```

You can use any expression on the right hand side of such an assignment as long as it can be converted to `vector2D const&`. In your case, `{1, 2}` indeed satisfies that requirement. For that reason,

```
v1 = {1,2};
```

is ok. It's as if you had used:

```
v1 = vector2D{1,2};
```

Comment: `{1, 2}` isn't an expression; there's a grammar rule that the assignment operator can be followed by a braced list